# if there is a existing resource then use it as a data

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

Is there an if else select in Terraform? There are many resource are configured already manually in the Azure portal. Is there a way to detect the resource by if else select statement in Terraform, so that if the resource is exit then I used it as a data otherwise create the resources.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try to build something like that with custom data sources and then having a count parameter on the resource itself that is 1 when the data source is not found and 0 otherwise causing the resource to be created if not found and not doing anything otherwise.

**BUT you should not do that**. What you should do instead is define the resource in terraform as you want the resource to be and then run `terraform import` statements to import the existing azure resource into your terraform state.

Answer (score 3):

Because Terraform has a declarative programming model, it doesn't really work to write statements like "read this if it exists or create it if not", because the act of creating it changes the outcome of the condition and would therefore cause Terraform to oscillate between creating and destroying the object.

There's some more detail on this subject in the Terraform documentation's guide on Module Composition, in the section [Conditional Creation of Objects](https://www.terraform.io/docs/modules/composition.html#conditional-creation-of-objects).

That guide suggests a different approach of writing a child module that takes the possibly-already-existing object as an input variable, and then having the calling module either declare that it will manage that object or declare that it intends to read an existing object:

```
# In situations where the AMI will be directly managed:

resource "aws_ami_copy" "example" {
  name              = "local-copy-of-ami"
  source_ami_id     = "ami-abc123"
  source_ami_region = "eu-west-1"
}

module "example" {
  source = "./modules/example"

  ami = aws_ami_copy.example
}
```

```
# Or, in situations where the AMI already exists:

data "aws_ami" "example" {
  owner = "9999933333"

  tags = {
    application = "example-app"
    environment = "dev"
  }
}

module "example" {
  source = "./modules/example"

  ami = data.aws_ami.example
}
```

This is an example of using module composition to decompose your configuration into smaller parts, so each of your configurations can use whatever subset of your modules are relevant to the specific situation it's modelling and connect them in different ways to produce different results, rather than trying to write a single "super-module" that covers all of the possibilities all at once.